# Firebase authentication Email link passwordless - Do I have to make my own server side app to handle authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've followed the guide here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth and am able to make an email get sent out successfully.

If I click that link on my desktop, it tries to take me to a website with the following image[image: should this be a server?]

Should I be writing my own server based app to authenticate this? I assumed Firebase would handle that for me. The guide doesn't mention anything about what happens at all.

It does talk about this

```
 // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
            .setUrl("https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234")
```

I changed it to use the domain of my firebase app/project e.g. myapp-123456.firebaseapp.com, assuming that Firebase would have something to handle this.

Am I missing a large section of documentation?

Comment: [This part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_an_android_app) of the documentation shows you have to set up Dynamic Links.

Comment: @JenPerson - I've got that part working, if I open the email on the device it works, but if I open the email on my laptop/desktop, then I get the above image

Comment: What is the behavior that you expect in this situation? That would help me suggest a solution.

Comment: So I kind of expected firebase to have some way of authenticating my user after they click the email. It should go to a firebase page, that is setup with my account details in it, and confirm the user is who they say they are. Do I have to write my own web server and host it on firebase in order to achieve that?

Comment: So to be clear, you want the user to be able to click on the link in the email while on *desktop*, and then they be signed in on the *Android app*?

Comment: Sorry, it's not about signing up, but validating the email link. That should be doable anywhere. Whether on the phone or on a desktop/laptop. If you click the validate email link, it should go to a website (I assume as part of the firebase app/console, something that you guys have written, not me) and it validates the email address. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184333/discussion-between-jen-person-and-russ-wheeler).